# How do I recursively check the child contexts of a given context in antlr?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I am working with a really large grammar, and there is a loop in the CFG, but no infinite recursions.

I need to check all the children of a specific context, and if my target context is among those children, then I need to throw an error.

Suppose if my grammar was like

```
    Sentence
    :   Nouns 'AND' Sentence
    |   Pronouns 'AND' Sentence
    |   'WITH APPLESAUCE'
    ;
    
    Nouns  
    :   Names
    |   Places
    |   Animals
    |   Things
    ;
    
    Names
    :   word 'AND' Sentence
    ;
        
    word
    :   (A-Z) (a-z)* // just any word
    ;
```

And I had to make sure that if a Sentence has a Names word, then the Sentence coming from that Names rule must not have any other Names? ie,

```
    Sentence ->
    Nouns 'AND' 'WITH APPLESAUCE' ->
    Names 'AND' 'WITH APPLESAUCE' ->
    word 'AND' Sentence 'AND' 'WITH APPLESAUCE', in this case,
```

`word 'AND' Names 'AND' 'WITH APPLESAUCE'` is invalid, but `word 'AND' Places 'AND' 'WITH APPLESAUCE'` is valid?

I tried going through the antlr documentation, but couldn't find anything for recursive search of children. I know that antlr generates a parse tree, so I thought it might be possible to check if there was a specific child/grandchild/n-th child context from a given point.

Comment: Yup, I meant to say it doesn't have any infinite loop recursions because it consumes some terminals. Edited the post to say it too, ty.

Do you have an idea where I can find a solution?

Comment: In other words, you do not want a `name` as a decendent of `name`, i.e. in xpath notation `not(//name//name)`. This is an easy check. What is hard about this?

Comment: By the way, this cannot be a realistic Antlr grammar. `Names` begins with a uppercase letter, which means that it is a lexer symbol. Yet the rule that defines it has symbol `word` on the right hand side, which is a parser rule because it starts with a lowercase letter. A lexer rule cannot have a parser rule symbol on the right hand side. The tool would never accept this.

Comment: right, it's easy to check if I know the exact fixed path between the 2 Name contexts. But this is a sample grammar, and in the real case it's got multiple paths to get to the second Name context, and there's no way to pin down every single one.

Comment: '//name' never means a fixed path. It means "a descendent of" through the `children` relationship that ends in a `name` node. The expression can be inverted into one that deals with ancestors, which would be more efficient when implemented using an Antlr visitor or listener. But, you will need to identify what parse tree structures are invalid for your language.

Answer (score 0):

ANTLR will create a [`ParseTree`](https://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/ParseTree.html) from your input. This `ParseTree` has a `getChild(int)` method, which returns a `ParseTree` as well. Use it to dive into your root tree and find out if a certain rule is used inside another.

Or use a [listener](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/listeners.md) and keep track of when a `enterSentence(...)` call happens. When that does, keep an instance variable inside your listener and then also implement `enterNames(...)`, which will throw an exception when the instance variable from `enterSentence(...)` is already set.

Pseudo code:

```
class YourListener extends YourGrammarBaseListener {

  boolean insideSentence = false

  void enterSentence(...) {
    insideSentence = true
  }

  void exitSentence(...) {
    insideSentence = false
  }

  void enterNames(...) {
    if (insideSentence) {
      throw Error()
    }
  }
}
```